# How do I get a column's default definition for a table on another server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get a column's default definition when the column's table is on another server?

I tried querying `diffserver.dbname.sys.default_constraints` directly, only to discover that the `sys.default_constraints` view uses `OBJECT_DEFINITION` for the "definition" column, and that obviously doesn't work on another server. (It doesn't even work in a different database.)

For example, this query returns all NULLs in the "definition" column when "diffserver" is a different server than the one you're currently on. (This query assumes a linked server to diffserver.)

```
select * from diffserver.somedb.sys.default_constraints
```

The reason I'm wanting to do this is to see all of a table's column definitions just from the meta data, and I can successfully do so for everything but the default constraints. I can get the constraint *name*, but not the definition, due to the above issue. This is the full query, just for context.

```
SELECT o.name,
       c.column_id AS num,
       c.name AS "column",
       CASE
         WHEN t.name IN ('char','varchar','binary','varbinary')
           THEN t.name + '(' + CASE c.max_length WHEN -1 THEN 'max' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS varchar) END + ')'
         WHEN t.name = 'datetime2'
           THEN t.name + '(' + CAST(c.scale AS varchar) + ')'
         WHEN t.name IN ('decimal','numeric')
           THEN t.name + '(' + CAST(c.precision AS varchar) + ISNULL(','+CAST(c.scale AS varchar),'') + ')'
         WHEN t.name IN ('float','real')
           THEN CASE WHEN c.precision <= 24 THEN 'real' ELSE 'float' END
         WHEN t.name IN ('nchar','nvarchar')
           THEN t.name + '(' + CASE c.max_length WHEN -1 THEN 'max' ELSE CAST(c.max_length/2 AS varchar) END + ')'
         ELSE
           t.name
       END AS "type",
       CASE c.is_nullable WHEN 1 THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END AS nulls,
       ISNULL(dc.definition,'') AS "default",
       CASE c.is_identity WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE '' END AS ident
  FROM sys.objects o
          INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
          LEFT JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
          LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON c.default_object_id = dc.object_id
 WHERE o.name = 'sometable'
   AND o.type = 'U'
 ORDER BY o.name,c.column_id
```

Is there another way to get a column's default definition from another server in SQL 2008+? (I've tried it on SQL 2008 and 2012.)

UPDATE:
Based on an answer here, I've discovered another piece of information. The servers on which I'm doing this have over a dozen databases on them. I've run the following query substituting each database name in turn for the "dbname" in the query (IOW, if diffserver has db1, db2, and db3, I ran the query three times, substituting each of db1,db2,db3 for "dbname" in the query):

```
select * from openquery(diffserver,'select name,object_id,definition from dbname.sys.default_constraints')
```

That query returns NULL in the definition column for every row, for every database, except one database. That one database is not my user's default database. It's also not the database that I am in on the current server. So why does that one database work (rhetorical question)? I haven't figured that out yet. It *might* be that it was the first database installed on the server, but that's conjecture. (I believe it was the first database installed, the conjecture part is whether "first" is what's causing it to work.)

So, if you happen to pick the one "right" database, then using openquery instead of a direct query will appear to work (as it did for one of the proposed answers). But, at least for me, it doesn't work on any other databases on the server. And I only found that one database by trial and error, so it definitely doesn't work as a generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this using openquery, which runs the query on the other server and it seems to work for me.

```
select * 
from openquery(linkedservername, 'SELECT o.name,
       c.column_id AS num,
       c.name AS "column",
       CASE
         WHEN t.name IN (''char'',''varchar'',''binary'',''varbinary'')
           THEN t.name + ''('' + CASE c.max_length WHEN -1 THEN ''max'' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS varchar) END + '')''
         WHEN t.name = ''datetime2''
           THEN t.name + ''('' + CAST(c.scale AS varchar) + '')''
         WHEN t.name IN (''decimal'',''numeric'')
           THEN t.name + ''('' + CAST(c.precision AS varchar) + ISNULL('',''+CAST(c.scale AS varchar),'''') + '')''
         WHEN t.name IN (''float'',''real'')
           THEN CASE WHEN c.precision <= 24 THEN ''real'' ELSE ''float'' END
         WHEN t.name IN (''nchar'',''nvarchar'')
           THEN t.name + ''('' + CASE c.max_length WHEN -1 THEN ''max'' ELSE CAST(c.max_length/2 AS varchar) END + '')''
         ELSE
           t.name
       END AS "type",
       CASE c.is_nullable WHEN 1 THEN ''NULL'' ELSE ''NOT NULL'' END AS nulls,
       ISNULL(dc.definition,'''') AS "default",
       CASE c.is_identity WHEN 1 THEN ''YES'' ELSE '''' END AS ident
  FROM sys.objects o
          INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
          LEFT JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
          LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
                            and dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
 WHERE  o.type = ''U''
 and o.name = ''sometable''
 ORDER BY o.name,c.column_id')
```

Comment: No, that's why I included the "select * from sys.constraints" — the definition column is blank, no matter what method you choose to get there. IOW, it's not a join problem, it's a the column is NULL problem. (Using default_object_id is a valid way to get to sys.default_constraints.)

Comment: Yea, I messed around w\ it more and the join was fine.  I get the definition column back from my linked server using openquery... you still don't?  I'd almost check the table you are looking at to make sure the default constraint is set as you expect it to be.

Comment: I added an update to the question. This only works for me on a single (seemingly random) database on the server, but not for any other database. The openquery works for that one database where the direct query didn't, but it doesn't work for any other database on the server. Weird.